# SWT: switch shell to full-screen mode

Tags: java, swt, fullscreen

How can I switch a shell (Windows, Linux, maybe OS X 10.7) to full-screen mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the methods [Shell.setFullScreen](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html#setFullScreen%28boolean%29) or [Shell.setMaximized](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Decorations.html#setMaximized%28boolean%29)

Comment: When I turn Firefox or Opera to full-screen mode, they don't show the menu bar. My SWT application does. Assuming, you are using `shell.setFullScreen` - do you set the shell menu to null to hide it?

Comment: @MikeL. The menu bar is inside the `Shell`, that why it's still visible in full screen mode. You have to hide it manually. Change the the `layoutData` of the bar (set a height to 0 for example) and call `shell.layout(true, true)` to remove it.

Comment: I called these methods with my `shell` but the window still fills only part of the screen. Do you know why that might be?